# import a.b also imports a?

Tags: python, python-import

When I import a subpackage in a package, can I rely on the fact that the parent package is also imported ?

e.g. this works

```
python -c "import os.path; print os.getcwd()"
```

Shouldn't I explicitly `import os` for `os.getcwd` to be available ?

Comment: I don't understand the question: if it works then where's the problem?

Comment: @freakish: Is it guaranteed to work for all packages?

Comment: @freakish: i believe he's asking why does it work, how does it work, can i rely on it, etc.

Answer (score 10):

There's an important thing to know about packages, that is that there is a difference between being loaded and being available.

With `import a` you load module `a` (which can be a package) and make it available under the name `a`.

With `from a import b` you load module `a` (which definitely is a package), then load module `a.b` and make *only this* available under the name `b`.  Notice that `a` also got loaded in the process, so any initialization this is supposed to do will have happened.

With `import a.b` you load both and make both available (under the names `a` and `a.b`).

Comment: but `import a` also makes both names available, does it not? `import os; os.path.join("this","works","without","import os.path")`

Comment: @adsmith:  That's just an oddity of `os.path`: the `os` package `__init__` deliberately imports `path` to make it available as `os.path`.  In general, no, both names won't be available. (Still time to edit this!  As user2357112 points out, I'm wrong about the `__init__`.)

Comment: Yeah, that's a special case.  `os.path` is added "manually" by the code in `os`.  If you only have a directory structure of `b` in `a`, then you need to explicitly `import a.b` to make `b` available.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Thank you, that was the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: `os` isn't a package, and it doesn't have `__init__`. It messes with `sys.modules` directly to make `import os.path` work.

Answer (score 5):

This is a good question.  If you look at the source code for `os.py` you find this line:

```
sys.modules['os.path'] = path
```

So there's our module.  But what's `path`? Well that depends on your OS.  For Windows, it's defined in this block:

```
elif 'nt' in _names:
    name = 'nt'
    linesep = '\r\n'
    from nt import *
    try:
        from nt import _exit
    except ImportError:
        pass
    import ntpath as path

    import nt
    __all__.extend(_get_exports_list(nt))
    del nt
```

Basically, `os.path` is special in this context.

**Short version:** Python does some stuff behind the scenes to make `os.path`. You probably shouldn't rely on it to get other modules.  "Explicit is better than implicit" is how the zen goes.

Comment: `os.path` is special, but the import rules aren't affected by this special case.  The same thing happens if you do `import scipy.stats`.  The `stats` submodule is normally *not* imported with scipy.  But doing `import scipy.stats` **does** import `scipy` as well.

Answer (score 2):

It works and it is reliable. What happens under the hood is when you do

```
import os.path
```

then `os` gets imported and then `os.path`.

Comment: This seems like inconsistent behavior. Why not just `import os` then to do `os.path.join` or what-have-you?

Comment: @adsmith I don't understand your question. What's inconsistent? I'm not telling to use it, I'm saying that it's a feature. Noone has to use it.

Comment: "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it." But `import os` and `import os.path` do the same thing. It's inconsistent with the Zen of Python, which is why I'm questioning it.

Comment: MarkDickinson and Alfe answered me in a comment below. `os.path` is an oddity, since `os` imports it in its `__init__`. Most modules don't work such that `import a` also imports `a.b`

Comment: @adsmith That's correct. Two ways just happen to do the same in this case. Also note that actually most modules do such nested imports.

Comment: @freakish Yeah, by accident :-/  Python has no feasible way (i. e. without using `del` explicitly or such) of importing something privately (i. e. without exporting it as well), so the name spaces get polluted.  A problem arises if such an accidental inner import in module A of a module B is used by an application which just imports A and the structure of module A later is changed not to import that module B anymore.  But in Python we have such things all the time and live with it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can rely on it always working.  Python has to include `os` in the namespace for `os.path` to work.

What won't work is using the `from os import path` notation.  In that case, the os module is *not* brought into the namespace, only `path`.